# SSIS Change a date format

Tags: sql, ssis, ansi-sql

I have a datetime format that is displayed as the following:

'13-10-2016 11:58:00'

I require it to be shown as :

'2016-10-13 11:58:00'

How can I change the expression below in order to match this?

Expression:

```
"SELECT _sessions.session_id AS session_id,   _sessions.user_id AS user_id,   _sessions.updated_at FROM public._sessions _sessions" + (@[User::IncrementalOrFullLoad] == "F" ? "" : " WHERE
```

Current output:

```
SELECT _sessions.session_id AS session_id,   _sessions.user_id AS user_id,   _sessions.updated_at FROM public._sessions _sessions WHERE  
_sessions.updated_at  > '13-10-2016 11:58:00'
```

Comment: `datetime` doesn't have an inherent format, the way it's shown depends on your local settings. If you want to display a certain format, you'll have to convert it to a `varchar`

Answer (score 1):

Producing string from a datetime variable as **YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss** is simple

```
(DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)@[User::YourDateTimeVar]
```

The first type cast to **DBTIMESTAMP** is necessary to avoid format ambiguity. Without it, SSIS .Net process would cast datetime variable to string using process or system culture. First casting to DBTIMESTAMP fixes culture and yields desired result.